# Fluent nHibernate, ToManyBase, Generic usage

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have discovered the method `T Generic()` in the abstract class `ToManyBase<T, TChild, TRelationshipAttributes>` but I cannot find any documentation or examples of how this is used, or what it does. Can anyone enlighten me a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing of significance.

It's the equivalent of the NHibernate `generic=` attribute, which is simply away of explicitly specifying that a collection is a generic one. A holdover from NHibernate's pre-generic days.